# Mathematical methods for solving pair-wise cheapest path.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, soft-question, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Two trains need to go two different routes. The first train must start at $A_1$ and stop at $B_1$ and the second train $A_2$ and $B_2$. They start at the same time. Let us assume no two trains can be on the same track at the same time for risk of collision. How can we plan so that the total cost/time for traveling is minimized? The total cost/time is defined to be the sum of the costs/times for the individual trains and it is not necessarily symmetric.

---

A minimal example as requested by @quasi which should be easy to test all cases:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&3\\3&0&1\\1&3&0\end{array}\right]$$

The matrix to be interpreted (row 1):

1. Go to 3 from 1 costs 3
2. Go to 2 from 1 costs 1
3. To stay at 1 costs 0.

And the objectives:

1. $T_1$ should go from $A_1 = 1$ to $B_1 = 3$
2. $T_2$ should go from $A_2 = 2$ to $B_2 = 1$

Unless I am having a major brain-fart, the solution should be

1. $T_1 : 1\to 2\to 3$ at cost $1+1=2$
2. $T_2 : 2\to 3\to 1$ at cost $1+1=2$

for a total cost of $2+2 = 4$

Comment: Can you provide numerical examples, one which you can easily solve, and one which is not obvious?

Comment: @quasi I have provided a relatively easy case. I think it would be easy enough to come up with a difficult case. Just make it have many stations should make it harder, no?

Comment: There is only one track, right? The stations are on a straight line, in numerical order, right? So if there are $3$ stations, $1,2,3$, any trip from station $1$ to station $3$ must pass station $2$, right? If so, why can't train $1$ go from station $1$ to station $2$ (time $1$), while train $2$ waits at station $2$, and then both trains can finish (simultaneously) in time $1$, so the total (simultaneous) time is $1+1=2$?

Comment: @quasi There is a track between every pair of stations in this example. Not having a track would mean an infinite cost. I.e. replacing $3$ and $0$ by $\infty$ in the matrix.

Comment: It appears I don't really understand the problem, so I'll leave it for others to deal with. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better solution (in terms of computational complexity), but here is a nice theoretical reduction:

Construct a pair graph $G^2$, where vertices are pairs of nodes of $G$, and edges are $(v_1, v_2) \to (u_1, u_2)$ if $v_i \to u_i$ are edges in $G$ and there is no collision. The cost of such edge is obviously the sum of costs, and you want to find the cheapest route from $(A_1,A_2)$ to $(B_1, B_2)$.

Here is a concrete example (I've removed the loops, because even without them the diagram is quite complicated):

[image: graph and its square]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'm not sure I know enough of graph theory to understand the answer. :)

Comment: @mathreadler Check out the diagram, I hope it will help you. I'm not sure if I got it exactly right, so let me know if you spot some mistakes.

Comment: wow I am amazed by the pretty graphs. how did you make them?

Comment: and yes now it makes more sense! but i dont see how to approach the squared graph with anything else than brute force. maybe there is some source of such graph algorithms i can read up on?

Comment: @mathreadler The picture was made in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). As for algorithms, plain Dijkstra's shortest path (run on the squared graph) should work just fine.

Comment: but we first need to disqualify all with same numbers, don't we? but yes i also think Dijkstra should work.

Comment: @mathreadler It depends what do you interpret as collision, if you look closely, you can see on the right picture that I've removed 6 arcs from the graph: $1 \leftrightarrow 2$, $2 \leftrightarrow 3$ and $1 \leftrightarrow 3$. But yes, you remove the unwanted arcs/vertices first (e.g., if you want to disallow two trains being in the same vertex, just remove pairs (1,1), (2,2), etc. from the graph).

Comment: yes the 1,1 et.c. was how I intended it, but of course it could be interpreted differently